# Struct with partial move errors

Tags: rust

I've got a simple struct and two instances of it as below:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct User {
    first: String,
    last: String,
    age: u32,
}

let u1 = User {
    first: String::from("John"),
    last: String::from("Doe"),
    age: 22,
};

let u2 = User {
    first: String::from("Mary"),
    ..u1
};

println!("user: {:#?}", u1);
```

Error message:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `u1`
  --> src/main.rs:20:29
   |
15 |       let u2 = User {
   |  ______________-
16 | |         first: String::from("Mary"),
17 | |         ..u1
18 | |     };
   | |_____- value moved here
19 | 
20 |       println!("user: {:#?}", u1);
   |                               ^^ value borrowed here after partial move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `u1.last` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I tried to revise it to `..&u1` hoping it will pass the borrow check so that I could spread in the base struct (u1) to u2, but to no avail, wondering is it even possible for what I wanted to do here?

I understand it's because `u1.last` is a `String`, hence needing to pass a reference, but I'm not sure how to make it work in this scenario.

Comment: *needing to pass a reference* — pass it to what? Your type `User` requires ownership of the `String`: `last: String`.

Comment: I thought this would work, but no.

```
let u2 = User {
    first: String::from("Mary"),
    ..u1
};
```

Comment: Why not just make first and last variable types `&'static str` instead of `String`? And then just do `"John"`, or whatever, instead of `String::from("John")` and so forth?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `User` type contains the type `String`, which owns the string data that it has (and doesn't impl `Copy`), which is why two users can't point to the same name in memory.

The solution you probably want:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct User {
    first: String,
    last: String,
    age: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let u1 = User {
        first: String::from("John"),
        last: String::from("Doe"),
        age: 22,
    };

    let u2 = User {
        first: String::from("Mary"),
        ..u1.clone() // Copy the strings into the new user 
        // (it also copies first, which is then thrown away? Maybe the compiler optimizes this away)
    };

    println!("user: {:#?}", u1);

}
```

but if you really want to have two users point to the same name in memory (pretty sure you don't), there are a couple of options:

- You can change `String` to `&'static str`. This however means that you have to specify it when you compile. (You can't have a user type in their name at runtime, and store it in user)

  ```
  #[derive(Debug)]
  struct User {
      first: &'static str,
      last: &'static str,
      age: u32,
  }

  fn main() {
      let u1 = User {
          first: "John",
          last: "Doe",
          age: 22,
      };

      let u2 = User {
          first: "Mary",
          ..u1
      };

      println!("user: {:#?}", u1);
  }
  ```

  - You can use a `Rc` to keep track of the references to a piece of memory. This way you don't have to worry about lifetimes and who's owning what. (Comes at a tiny runtime cost though)

  ```
  use std::rc::Rc;

  #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
  struct User {
      first: Rc<String>,
      last: Rc<String>,
      age: u32,
  }

  fn main() {
      let u1 = User {
          first: Rc::new(String::from("John")),
          last: Rc::new(String::from("Doe")),
          age: 22,
      };

      let u2 = User {
          first: Rc::new(String::from("Mary")),
          ..u1.clone() // Clone the references, not the actual string. For strings with just a couple characters, the time difference is completely negligible)
      };

      println!("user: {:#?}", u1);
  }
  ```

  - Use a `Rc<Mutex<String>>` instead if you want to modify the name later, and have it change in both u1 and u2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this perfectly answered my question!

Comment: @DonKlein, please upvote the answer if it solves the problem - this helps the person answering the question, as well as people searching for solutions. I had the same problem, and the explanation provided by Prime_Aquasix nailed it :)