# How to solve partial move error when accessing struct fields?

Tags: rust, struct, rust-cargo

I'm using a field of the struct ClientError (implemented in the Solana client):

```
#[derive(Error, Debug)]
#[error("{kind}")]
pub struct ClientError {
    pub request: Option<rpc_request::RpcRequest>,

    #[source]
    pub kind: ClientErrorKind,
}
```

Below is how it's used in my code:

```
Err(err: ClientError) => {
  if let MyError(myError) = err.kind {
    ...
  }

  return Err(custom_error(err, ...));
}
```

Which gives me the error:

```
use of partially moved value: `err`
partial move occurs because value has type `CustomType`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How can I solve this partial move error? I have seen this SO answer: [Struct with partial move errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422438/struct-with-partial-move-errors). But suggests using `&'static str` which isn't valid for me & I don't want to use `Rc<Mutex<..>>` either.

Comment: Can you borrow?

Comment: Tip: `if let MyError(ref MyError)` or `if let MyError(...) = &err.kind`.

Comment: [Destructuring](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/move/partial_move.html) is the solution.

Comment: you could also clone it